# openssl encryption with public key segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, openssl

From the shell, using openssl commands below I can encrypt a secret message with public key and decrypt it with private key.

```
# private key generation
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 1024

# public key generation from private key
openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout > pubkey.pub

# encrypt a message with public key
openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey pubkey.pub -in msg > out

# decrypt a message with private key
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey key.pem -in out
```

Now I would like to do same thing with openssl development library in C. When I use the code below and compile with `gcc main.c -lcrypto` it does not give error and prints out `128` as size. I can encrypt and decrypt messages successfully. However, I would like to hide private key from the user of the source code and use only public key for encryption. Hence, I tried to second version of this code which seems correct to me, but it does not work, it always gives segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>


int main(){
char error_message[120];
unsigned char to[128];

FILE *pem_file = fopen("key.pem", "rb");

if (pem_file == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
  exit(1);
}


RSA *rsa  = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(pem_file, NULL, NULL, NULL);
printf("%d\n", RSA_size(rsa));
}
```

Second version: Reading public key and initializing rsa object.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>


int main(){
char error_message[120];
unsigned char to[128];

FILE *pem_file = fopen("pubkey.pub", "rb");

if (pem_file == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
  exit(1);
}


RSA *rsa  = PEM_read_RSAPublicKey(pem_file, NULL, NULL, NULL);
printf("%d\n", RSA_size(rsa));
}
```

Comment: Please check the return value of `fopen()` and make surce it is valid.

Comment: There is no problem with file. I can encrypt with same file using shell command `rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public_key.pub -in msg > out` and decrypt it later with private pem file.

Comment: That cannot guarantee the `fopen()` in your code will success.

Comment: Ok, I put all controls and print the file's content, there is no problem with file, it still gives `segmentation fault` while encrypting.

Comment: The other possible problem is the size of `to`, according to `RSA_public_encrypt(3SSL)`, it must be `RSA_size(rsa)`.

Comment: The problem is actually at `PEM_read_RSAPublicKey` Before encryption I just `RSA *rsa = PEM_read_RSAPublicKey(pem_file, NULL, NULL, NULL); 
    printf("%d\n", RSA_size(rsa)); ` doing this operation and it gives error. How will I initialize rsa object properly with public key. I have used other functions like `read from bio` but still does not change anything.

Comment: Please, edit your question according to information you gave in comments.

Comment: @mustafa.yavuz What is the error message gave by `ERR_error_string()`?

Comment: I edit the message, there is no error message, it just gives segmentation fault.

Comment: Hmm, I have tried `PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY` before it did not work, but now it is working. I have missed something before. Now there is no problem. Thank you leeduhem..

Comment: Now I have problem with reading from memory instead file. I posted to question to link you sent. I used `-outform DER` option but did not work.

Comment: The 2nd version dumps as `PEM_read_RSAPublicKey()` returns `NULL` and passing `NULL` to `RSA_size()` makes it choke.

Comment: Hi alk, the problem was solved, solution is posted under the thread leeduhem has sent. Now I can read from file but I need to read from memory also using `bio` operations like `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY`. However, they are not working as well. It is stated on the post it was about the format of the public key, I tried all combinations but could not achieve it.